# Android Runtime permission don't accept ok, only deny

Tags: android, google-maps, android-permissions

After fixing another connected problem, now i have this one: i can't click on 'Ok' in the dialog to handle location permission, only on deny.

If i granted permission in manual way (via settings) i have this in log:

> W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates not found.

but i created the key and obtained the json file.

This is my simple activity:

```
package com.marcocreation.***********;

import *;

public class Maps extends AppCompatActivity implements OnClickListener, OnMapReadyCallback, ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private Location mLastLocation;

    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    private static final int REQUEST_LOCATION = 1503;

    private double latitude, longitude;

    private static final int LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1;

    private boolean mPermissionDenied = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        // Create an instance of GoogleAPIClient.
        if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                    .build();
        }

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(this);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);


    }
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    }

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    Log.i("inside","callback");
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_LOCATION: {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                // permission was granted, yay! Do the
                Log.i("permission", "done");

            } else {

                // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                // functionality that depends on this permission.
            }
            return;
        }

        // other 'case' lines to check for other
        // permissions this app might request
    }
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
private void updateMaps(){
    String locationPermission = Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION;
    int hasPermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,locationPermission);
    String[] permissions = new String[] { locationPermission };
    if (hasPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        requestPermissions(permissions, REQUEST_LOCATION);

    }
    else {
        // Phew - we already have permission!
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        Log.i("clicked", "here");
        // Access to the location has been granted to the app.
        mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
        if (mLastLocation != null) {
            latitude = mLastLocation.getLatitude();
            longitude = mLastLocation.getLongitude();
            Log.i("latitude", "" + latitude);
            Log.i("longitude", "" + longitude);
            LatLng sydney = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
        }
        Log.i("latitude", "" + latitude);
        Log.i("longitude", "" + longitude);
    }
}

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        Log.i("Connection", "OK");
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Log.i("Connection", "FAILED");
    }
}
```

Activity Layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.marcocreation.******.Maps">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_maps" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Included activity:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.marcocreation.******.Maps"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_maps">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.marcocreation.******.createMatch" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Sorry if i wrote stupid things, it's three days i'm going crazy with maps and i edited the code a lot of time.My idea is when i click on the right/down button camera will moves on the user position.

I tried also this lib: 
https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples/blob/master/ApiDemos/app/src/main/java/com/example/mapdemo/PermissionUtils.java

but nothing is changed

Comment: You are not handling `onRequestPermissionResult()` method.

Comment: i added it, but didn't change anything, it still doesn't accept "allow" only deny. I edit the code above to show you what i've done

Comment: It print "inside callback" but not "permission done"